# VMware FTP-client returns connection is refused. How to setup VMware firewall for FTP connection?

Tags: firewall, ftp

I have set up VMware vSphere home lab and tried to configure FTP connection to the third backup host (vCenter backup). No luck with default firewall configuration.

I have enabled/started FTP client using either vCenter (6.0 is running) and connected to the server using shell (https://www.starwindsoftware.com/blog/vmware-vcenter-server-appliance-vcsa-and-after-install-tricks). No changes were done to the  firewall settings.

The firewall drops connection and FTP server returns the connection was refused. But for a disabled firewall, it just works. I have no luck configuring the firewall using VMware knowledge base or VMware forums (https://communities.vmware.com/thread/56409?start=0&tstart=0). I found the documentation as outdated and not applicable for vCenter 6.0.

Any guidance how you got vCenter firewall working with ftp would be enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the firewall. Here how I made it works for my lab:

1. Enable SSH
2. Download `http://busybox.net/downloads/binaries/1.19.0/busybox-x86_64`
   You can find ftp client there
   ./busybox ftpput -v -u  -p  -P  HOSTNAME 
   It won't start, you need configure firewall in ESXi first.
3. Setup fixed list of FTP ports on FTP-server side.
4. Disable firewall `esxcli network firewall set --enabled false`
5. Find in the file /etc/vmware/firewall/service.xml
   `<service id='0021'>
   <id>ftpClient</id>`
   and add after
   `<rule id='0002'>
   <direction>outbound</direction>
   <protocol>tcp</protocol>
   <porttype>dst</porttype>
   <port>
   <begin>First port</begin>
   <end>Last port </end>
   </port>
   </rule>`
6. Enable the rule `<enabled>true</enabled>`
7. Start firewall 
   `esxcli network firewall set --enabled true`

The following blog-posts may also be useful.
https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1868
https://communities.vmware.com/thread/344090